# passing a variable to django form class

Tags: django-views, django-forms

I need to pass an integer variable to the class in forms.py

```
form.py
class GeeksForm(forms.Form): 
    def __init__(self, *args,number, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
        filename =  "downloaded{}.csv".format(number)
        data = open(filename, encoding = "utf8")
        csv_data = csv.reader(data)
        data_lines = list(csv_data)
        property_dic = {}
        ...created dictionary...
        key1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices = property_dic[list1[i]] )
```

so as per comment below, am throwing away key1 after init ends not actually creating a field.

1. so how to fix this?
2. how to construct the form field above init . looked documentation. couldnt  understand.
3. and override it. with dictionary data

Comment: Exactly what will you *do* with the value?

Comment: i will use it to access file . like this                                                                                                filename =  "downloaded{}.csv".format(num1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override the constructor and process the number. I would however advice to use a named parameter, because a Django form already has some positional parameters, making it quite "ambiguous":

```
class GeeksForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, number, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # do something with number
        # …
```

then you construct the form with:

```
def name_view(request, num1):
    form = forms.GeeksForm(request.POST, number=num1)
```

Comment: @AniketPatil: that is because you construct the `GeeksForm` likely *somewhere* else without the `number=...`.

Comment: if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.GeeksForm(request.POST,number = num1)                                           i fixed here , now i am getting keyerror while accessing the data user entered                i am accessing it using this lines  data = form.cleaned_data['key1']

Comment: @AniketPatil: well that is likely because you aim to retrieve data for which there was no form field, or you access it through `request.POST` directly...

Comment: how to access it, if not by request.POST directly

Comment: @AniketPatil: with `form.cleaned_data`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data

Comment: i have updated question, can you please tell me what should have went wrong

Comment: @AniketPatil: you never constructed a form field. You can not just define a local variable that is a field and expect Django to "pick it up". You normally already construct a field at the class level, and then override the choices. See for example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships

Comment: i was able use the number in form.py  and  create 2-tupels  which i verified by printing it in terminal ,  so number is working , now the issue i am facing is how to construct a field at class level and then override choices , the way i have done prints out key1 and key2 as follows : key1 is
<select name="key1" id="id_key1">
</select>
key2 is
<select name="key2" id="id_key2">
</select>                                                                                                                            
    i have updated question and shown forms.py completely . please have a look .

Comment: @AniketPatil: of course you can print that in the form, but you only construct a field that you "throw away" when the `__init__` function ends... So you never "attach" your field to the form.

Comment: @AniketPatil: I think this boils down to understanding Python's object-oriented data model (OO). Right now, it looks like there is some misunderstanding on that part.